# Undefined variable: layoutFactory - Magento 2.4.3

Tags: error, magento2.4.3, bug

Last night I updated our 3rd party payment module, when I did this I got an error under setup:upgrade called "area code is not set". Apparently, this was a Magento 2.4.3 bug and I used this to fix the bug: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/d0f220111548123a7a77102cc516b1043d54d905

But after this, we get a new error when we try and print packing slips:
Notice: Undefined variable: layoutFactory in /chroot/home/xxxxx/xxxxxxxx/html/vendor/magento/module-payment/Helper/Data.php on line 180

Here is the code i did:

```
  {
    $layout = $layout ?: $layoutFactory->create();
    $blockType = $info->getMethodInstance()->getInfoBlockType();
    $block = $layout->createBlock($blockType);
    $block->setInfo($info);
    return $block;
}
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this by replacing

> $layout = $layout ?: $layoutFactory->create()

; with

> $layout = $layout ?: $this->layoutFactory->create();

```
 $layout = $layout ?: $this->layoutFactory->create();
 $blockType = $info->getMethodInstance()->getInfoBlockType();
 $block = $layout->createBlock($blockType);
 $block->setInfo($info);
 return $block;
```

And then you can create a patch or override the changes on your custom module.

Comment: Hi, I get this error now: Notice: Undefined property: Magento\Payment\Helper\Data\Interceptor::$layoutFactory in /chroot/home/xxxxx/xxxxxxx/html/vendor/magento/module-payment/Helper/Data.php on line 178

Comment: Yes, try to replace  $layoutFactory with $this->layoutFactory->create();

Comment: I did replace it with $this->layoutFactory->create(); , then i got the new error i just added to the comment abover